# Cutting-and-pasting problem using develop.wolframcloud.com

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I've just started to use develop.wolframcloud.com.

If I issue a command, then I can't seem to be able to cut-and-paste
the output of the command, as, of course, I have long been able to do
with Mathematica notebooks, in general.

Comment: I find I can copy the previous output in two ways: After an evaluation I can hold shift and press Up once, this highlights the previous output, then I just copy as normal. Or if I move my mouse to the cell bracket for the output (on the right of the window), it shows the little gear icon which gives me access to a context menu for the output.  This is different than in a normal notebook, but it works for me.

Comment: Thanks, Jason B. I do now see the gear icon, and the menu that appears from clicking on it, but I don't see how to actually get the copy option to work in a standard cut-and-paste manner. To what is the cell being copied?